# JIRA implementation for process control and scrum

Tags: jira, scrum, process-control

I am reviewing JIRA for possible use within several development teams at the company I work for.  We use Scrum as a base for our project management.  We have good, self-organizing teams, almost no assigned work, etc.  JIRA seems great for some of these items, but something we are struggling with is handling the management of process vs technical tasks and something we call "issue bundling".

Process control.  Currently we will create a story, say "The graph on the Profit and Loss report has issues with overlapping legend text".  Okay, good enough.  We will then create a technical sub-task, for simplicity let's say it's "Research and correct the issue".  Next we have a set of process sub-tasks that we create.  Peer Review, Make Build, QA Testing, Merge, Track.  Each of these can then be independently assigned to users and placed into the Pending bin on our scrum board (BTW, we use a Pending, Awaiting Action, In Progress, Done, Merged model rather than a todo, in progress, done model).  Pending basically means, I'm waiting if I'm next in priority.  During development the programmers will grab the technical task, set themselves as assignee and move to in progress.  When they are done they will move it to the Done bin and then update the Peer Review process sub task to "Awaiting Action", and set the assignee to their code partner.  Emails are sent, peer review is done.  When that is completed the peer review partner will move Peer Review to the Done bin and set the Make Build sub task to the build manager and move it to Awaiting Action.  Build manager sees this, makes build, moves it to done and updates the QA Testing ticket to a Awaiting Action status, you get the point.

It's working, but are their any suggestions on alternatives, best practices, etc.  Is creating technical and process sub-tasks not the way to go?  One thing I notice is that we have to filter the issue list to hide the sub tasks and the scrum board can get pretty overwhelming for the stakeholder who just wants to see the status of the parent story.  Since the parent story does not move until the sub-tasks move they don't see anything that is of interest to them, not even if the story is "in progress" while the sub-tasks are moving.  Ugh.

Issue bundling.  We often have a set of issues that are related perhaps tightly, but typically more general.  For example, all issues that are related to reports in our software.  At the present there are say 15 known issues.  These issues may be on different reports in the system, with specific steps to reproduce, etc.  When we are gearing up for a sprint we will select bundles of these related issues.  The reason is that QA can more efficiently test a bunch of small fixes that are generally related in one pass rather than testing each report as a separate process.

Currently we move each issue to a subtask of a bundle.  The bundle for example might be simply called "Report Fixes 1", and it will have, for example, 5 sub-tasks that are technical, each being a different report bug to be fixed.  We can then add the process control items from above to the overall bundle.  We also know that we won't merge until all items in the bundle are done, so they all get the same version.

However, as stated above, visibility is reduced as you cannot see the status easily of the subtasks now that they are in the bundle.

Again, best practice?  Ideas?  How are others handling this?

Comment: Why not use a tool that supports scrum? JIRA can use [Greenhopper](https://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/overview)!

Answer (score 1):

Brian,

Have you considered combining your process sub-tasks (Peer Review, Make Build) and your Scrum board "bins" (Pending, Awaiting Action)? Subtasks are the usual way to provide parallel tasks in JIRA, but the way you describe the whole process it sounded more linear. If each story really gets bounced from one assignee to another, just change the assignee and the status.

"Issue bundling" sounds like Epics in GreenHopper to me. You can also do a similar thing using a Labels field (standard or custom) to group issues.

~Matt

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first item of the response.  Pending in our setup basically means no action has been taken (open/new).  Awaiting Action indicates that someone has put some effort into it but perhaps it's stalled (waiting for support to update us with steps to reproduce, waiting on a customer to call back to provide more details on a feature request, etc).  We use separate sub-tasks currently because we want to provide visibility as to the steps.  Part of my question was "is that best".  I don't see any description of how it is not best in your response.

Comment: On the second response.  Epics, we've tried epics.  I'm finding them to be a bit limited and I'm not sure about the flow of items in the epic.  For example, all items in an epic are not grouped together on the board.  That is no good for us.  When we used a whiteboard we would group them either by drawing lines around grouped items or by using the same color post-it notes for grouped items.  Both were very good visual indicators of the whole process.  As with above on the columns and sub-tasks.  That method worked well for indicating who had the next step too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we are handling this -

The process sub-tasks you mentioned are statuses in our implementation. So, I'll have the story broken into Technical tasks that the dev finishes and then moves the story to "Pending Review" status, from where it goes to Make Build and QA Testing and so on. This is pretty much what Matt said as well. This workflow gives the stakeholders the sense of the progress that is being made on the sprint and thus is very helpful.

As such there is nothing like best practice in JIRA, it is very flexible and one can use it the way one wants/needs.

I agree with you on Epics not being a complete solution. We overcome this by adding labels and creating filters and swimlanes based on these filters.